# TestPlugInRunnerd.exe + gmock

Tags: c++, tdd, googlemock, cppunit

We build our cppunit unittests as a dll and load it into TestPlugInRunnerd.exe to show our results. We write our own mocks but I'd like to start using a mocking framework such as gmock.

I downloaded gmock and linked against it without much in the way of problems. I have written a mock using gmock and it compiles fine. But then I read the following in the gmock faq:

```
If you want to use something other than Google Test (e.g. CppUnit or CxxTest) as your testing framework, just change the main() function in the previous section to:

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // The following line causes Google Mock to throw an exception on failure,
  // which will be interpreted by your testing framework as a test failure.
  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  ... whatever your testing framework requires ...
}

This approach has a catch: it makes Google Mock throw an exception from a mock object's destructor sometimes. With some compilers, this sometimes causes the test program to crash. You'll still be able to notice that the test has failed, but it's not a graceful failure.
```

I obviously don't have a main. What do I need to do to get gmock to work with my dll? Should I consider alternatives to gmock?

Thanks,

Barry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not possible that you don't have a main. Otherwise how would you execute your unit tests?

Second, you could create a static variable of a class where you call these two functions, like this :

```
struct GmockInitializer
{
  GmockInitializer()
  {
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(throw_on_failure) = true;
    ::testing::InitGoogleMock(0,0);  // << not sure about this. might not work
  }
};
GmockInitializer gmockInitializer;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I just figured out that you can use the enviroment variable GTEST_THROW_ON_FAILURE=1

Comment: @Baz Ok, but how do you initialize it?

Comment: @BЈовић You do not need a main in the DLL, just an external function which calls the gmock initialization and runs the tests.  This function can then be called from a TestPlugInRunnerd.EXE by loading the DLL and calling the external function.  I am guessing this is how he does it.